# Absolute position element on top of image of dynamic size

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay, aspect-ratio

My goal is to display an image of any dimension inside a div container, with an overlay over the image which is absolute positioned in the top right corner.

But here's the trick, the width & height of the container can be changed dynamically with JavaScript, and I want the image to be displayed in its correct aspect ratio within the container.

I have a working solution, but it requires me to set `max-width` and `max-height` of the image equal to the width and height of the div container. Is there a way to solve this without having to set the `max-width` of the img equal to the width of the container, and the same for the `max-height`? I tried solutions such as setting `max-height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` to the img, but it doesn't seem to help.

I'm open to all suggestions.

Here's my current solution:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: #666;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  max-width: 248px;
  max-height: 145px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="width: 248px; height: 145px;">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/bZmRQr8.jpg" />
      <div class="overlay">Avatar and name will be displayed here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not really sure what problem your having,.. just set the img width to 100%, the aspect ratio will work fine.

Comment: The image will not respect the container width and height if you set the img width to 100%. The expected result is in my question, where you can see gray area on the left and right side of the image.
If you set the img width to 100%, the image will overflow the container.

Comment: Still not really sure what issue your having..  I'll knock up a working snippet.

Comment: The issue is basically that I want to find a better pure-CSS solution for the img part, where I don't have to specify a specific max-width and max-height for the img. But the container part is fine, I want to control the size of that with JS.

Comment: Indeed, my snippet does this. The JS is only there to randomly change the container to show things working.

Comment: Whats wrong in setting max-width & max-height to 100%?

Comment: @RupeshJain I want to find a better pure-CSS solution for the img part. There's nothing wrong with setting max-width and max-height, but I don't want to involve JavaScript in that part.